# Fetch contenteditable=true data

Tags: javascript, html

I want to fetch data from div tag which set contenteditable=true
I have used autosuggestion in that..Data is successfully fetched but when I write item which is written in autosuggestion field then it wont be fetched because it add HTML tag and it wont save into database
**My code**
if data is changed:

```
var timeoutID;
$('[contenteditable]').bind('DOMCharacterDataModified', function () {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    $that = $(this);
    timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
        $that.trigger('change')
    }, 50)
});
$('[contentEditable]').bind('change', function () {
    getTextChangeContent();
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
function getTextChangeContent() {
    var ma = document.getElementById('myAudio');
    var remove = ma.src.slice(0, -4);
    var path = remove.substring(remove.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    var newPath = path.concat('.wav');
    var text_id = document.getElementById('textbox');
    var textdata = text_id.innerHTML;
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("getChangeContent")',
            dataType: "json",
            mtype: "post",
            data: { arg: varid, content: textdata, path: newPath },
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data + " DATA");
            }
        });
}
```

when I changed data and use autosuggestion then it will show data as

```
The door is blacl <span class="atwho-inserted">[[Ceilings]]</span>&nbsp;
```

How to ignore html tag and take only values of that?
Plz suggest me

Comment: Show the code for your getTextChangeContent method.

Comment: @KonstantinDinev PLEASE look at my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve `innerText` rather than `innerHTML` in order to ignore the HTML content. If you want only the content inside the html tag with class `.atwho-inserted`, then retrieve only that content.

```
var textdata = text_id.innerText;
```